# Как спозиционировать текст относительно центрированного фона родителя?

Tags: css

Шапка сайта растянута на 100% по ширине, и фоновое изображение при сжатии страницы обрезается справа и слева (выровнено по центру). CSS-код такой:

```
#header {
    background: url('../images/header.jpg') top no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
}
```

Внутри шапки есть текстовый блок фиксированной ширины, `position: absolute`. Блок должен быть расположен в определенной позиции на шапке и при уменьшении, когда она обрезается, оставаться в той же позиции. То есть, текст должен равномерно смещаться влево, видимо оставаясь на том же месте.

http://jsfiddle.net/v67dqk8q/

В представленном примере текст стоит на месте, даже `left` в процентах не спасает положение. Как этого достичь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Картинка центрируется, значит отступ слева меняется в 2 раза медленее, чем ширина экрана. Поэтому надо сделать так:

```
left: calc((100% - 969px) / 2 + 969px * .2);
```

Где 969px - ширина картинки. Левый отступ до картинки - это половина разности ширины экрана и ширины картинки. Если требуется разместить текст на 20% картинки, то надо вычислить это значение в пикселях и прибавить к левому отсупу.

http://jsfiddle.net/v67dqk8q/3/

```css
.header {
  background: url('http://images.forwallpaper.com/files/thumbs/preview/26/265899__the-old-furka-pass-switzerland-alps_p.jpg') top no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc((100% - 969px) / 2 + 969px * .2);
  top: 150px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <span class="text">Текст</span>
</div>
```

Ещё, как сказали выше, стоит добавить родителю `position:relative`, чтобы отсчёт вёлся от него, а не от документа.

И лучше не ставить пробелы вокруг знака равенства в html-разметке.

Ну и не забываем, про [поддержу `calc` в браузерах](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) и случаи того, когда он роняет IE.

При желании получить более кроссбраузерный вариант, можно заметить, что вычисляемое выражение [можно упростить](http://jsfiddle.net/v67dqk8q/4/) до (пока оставил выражение, чтобы подчеркнуть структуру)

```
left: calc(50% - 969px * .3);
```

т. е. получилась разность порцентов и пикселей. Такую штуку можно [заменить на](http://jsfiddle.net/v67dqk8q/5/)

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: calc(-969px * .3);
```

Или, уже без calc'ов:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -291px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v67dqk8q/6/

```css
.header {
  background: url('http://images.forwallpaper.com/files/thumbs/preview/26/265899__the-old-furka-pass-switzerland-alps_p.jpg') top no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -291px;
  top: 150px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <span class="text">Текст</span>
</div>
```

К этому решению можно было прийти и другим путём, но я написал свой :)

Кстати, при желании можно свопнуть значения `left` и `margin-left`:

```
margin-left: 50%;
left: -291px;
```

Не думаю, что это имеет какое-то значение, но в IE6 можно было наткнуться на проблемы перерисовки при отрицательных margin'ах.

Comment: Спасибо. Если не сложно, разъясните, пожалуйста, насчет пробелов вокруг знака равенства.

Comment: @nup, если честно, не знаю. Можно в куче мест найти эту рекомендацию, да и просто, не ставят их. Но вот почему, не могу найти. Могу только предположить, что когда-то какой-то браузер не мог это обработать. А может, и сейчас какие-то кастомные парсеры.

Comment: @nup, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/446173/178988 - посмотрим :)

Answer (score 2):

> То есть, текст должен равномерно смещаться влево, видимо оставаясь на
>   том же месте.

– эта фраза крайне сложна для понимания.

Может так:

```
<style type="text/css">
#header {
    background: url('http://pandastyle.ru/demo3/templates/nevado/images/bg-body.png') 50% 0;

    /* задаём для того, чтобы дочерние элементы с
       position: absolute позиционировались относительно 
       границ #header */
    position: relative;

    width: 100%; height: 550px;
}

#header #text-block {
    /* растягиваем блок на 100% ширины #header,
       приклеивая его к левой и правой границам */
    position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0;

    text-align: center; /* выраивниваем текст по центру */
    padding-right: 300px; /* смещаем текст от центра в нужную позицию */
}
</style>

<div id="header">
    <div id="text-block">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Фраза понимается довольно просто: текст относительно фона не должен смещаться.

Comment: Тогда такой способ. Код откорректировал. Вроде относительно фона при ресайзе окна не смещается.

Comment: Если предполагается наличие других элемнтов, то растягивание блока - не слишком хорошая идея, поскольку он будет их перекрывать. Хотя на это можно сделать костыль из нулевой высоты и переполнения.

Comment: @Qwertiy у него абсолютное позиционирование, так что не страшно. Особенно если другие элементы также будут позиционироваться абсолютно. Проблему с перекрыванием можно решить с помощью `z-index`. Полагаю также, что в моём примере `padding` можно заменить на `margin`. А можно вообще хитро поступить и сделать элемент кликопрозрачным с помощью CSS4-свойства `pointer-events: none`.

Comment: Margin поможет только для одного края, а с другого элемент останется. Напихать z-index'ов можно, но нужно ли? Я же показал вариант без растягивания элемента на всю строку.