# Почему не принято ставить пробелы вокруг html-атрибутов?

Tags: html, code-style

Весьма распространённая рекомендация не ставить пробелы вокруг html-атрибутов. Собственно, почти никто их и не ставит.

А почему собственно такая рекомендация возникла? Был ли какой-то браузрер, который не мог это обработать? Или раньше это не соответствовало стандарту?

Сейчас w3c-валидатор говорит, что код с пробелами корректен. Проверял на таком коде:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test</title>
<p data-x = any>
```

[Вот тут](http://geroin.sitecity.ru/stext_1912015104.phtml) достаточно необоснованно утверждается, что пробелы приведут к ошибке.

> Не вздумай ставить пробелы между именем атрибута, равенством и значением атрибута (это приведет к ошибке)! Между прочим, приличные люди пишут значение атрибута в кавычках. Хотя в большинстве случаев это необязательно, я все-таки рекомендую это делать.

Но где они к ней приведут? Судя по всему статья довольно древняя.

Comment: от противного: зачем их ставить и понижать читаемость?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю единственная причина - лишние символы увеличивают размер страницы, особенно у больших, тяжелых проектов. Не зря же все скрипты и стили сжимают удаляя все пробелы, и переносы строк.

Comment: А как же рекомендация ставить кавычки? Это те же два символа на значение. К тому же, есть минификаторы. [Вот тут](http://geroin.sitecity.ru/stext_1912015104.phtml) достаточно необоснованно утверждается, что пробелы приведут к ошибке. Но где они к ней приведут? Судя по заглавным буквам, статья весьма древняя.

Comment: Кавычки необходимы в тех случаях, когда значение атрибута содержит пробел, например. А статья и в самом деле довольно сомнительная.

Comment: Статья там средненькая, но не сомнительная. Да, если смотреть на неё с современным уровнем html/css, то там совершенно не то. Но очень похоже, что она просто старше. Это начало развития html, когда теги писали большими буквами, доктайпа не было и css, возможно, тоже. Найти сейчас статьи того времени достаточно проблематично. Даже про IE Quirks 5 найти что-то сложно, а это ещё раньше.